# Expectation Maximization opencv-Log Likelihood value

Tags: c++, opencv, gaussian, mixture-model, expectation-maximization

I'm estimating the parameters of a GMM using EM,

When I use my Matlab script And run the EM code i get a **single value of "log-likelihood**"..

However in opencv the output of **EM.train** gives a matrix which contained the **loglikelihood value of every sample**.

How do I get a single log likelihood value? Do I need to take the minimum of all the loglikelihood values of all samples or the sum of all loglikelihood values?

Answer (score 0):

You need sum of log probabilities of datapoints which you use to estimate probability density function. You'll get loglikelihood of your estimation.

You can find good explanation in ["Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning" book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387310738)

Comment: @AndreySmorodov.. Im having a bit of a trouble here-the book isnt helping me too much either...EM.train outputs a "loghood" matrix which is of dimension (no_of_samples*1)  and a "probs" matrix which is (no_of_samples*no_of_components).....when you mean "probabilities of datapoints" Im guessing I should use the "probs" matrix and sum all the log values in it?

Comment: You can compute loglikelihood as described here: http://www.schraudolph.org/teach/ml03/MLmix.pdf but as I know, loglikelihood value cares no userful information, it used for optimization purpose only. For finding mu, or sigma for example. And it evaluated for training set, not for each example. No, I didn't mean probs matrix values, it contains probs for posterior probabilities of each Gaussian mixture component you need probability for etire pdf you estimate.

Comment: By the way, I've just look at opencv's EM source, there is line: trainLogLikelihood = sum(trainLogLikelihoods)[0]; I think this is the answer you looking for. You need sum values of loglikelihood matrix.